# Android - WebView onReceivedError opposite

Tags: android, android-webview

How do I know if there were no errors in loading a page in `webview`? Here is the code for the `onReceivedError`:

```
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
            view.stopLoading();  // may not be needed
            switch (Locale.getDefault().toString()) {
                case "es_ES":
                    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/errorPage.forRestActivities.es_ES.HTML");
                    break;
                default:
                    view.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/errorPage.forRestActivities.en_US.HTML");
                    break;
            }
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting a flag (isError) did the trick. The flag is set to false when created, as an error is not what's supposes to happens. If it does happens then the flag is set to true. That flag is evaluated at `onPageFinished`. If it's true the buttons are not showed otherwise they're

Answer (score 0):

I would use onPageFinished() for that.

Comment: That's what I did with the flag, as I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I update my answer to better reflect what was the solution I found